# Can I merge yum and yum-cron excludes?

Tags: centos, yum

In my `/etc/yum.conf` I have a bunch of stuff that was put there by an ansible deployment

```
exclude= tuned-profiles-origin-node  origin-tests  origin-sdn-ovs  origin-recycle  origin-pod  origin-node  origin-master  origin-dockerregistry  origin-clients-redistributable  origin-clients  origin  docker*1.20*  docker*1.19*  docker*1.18*  docker*1.17*  docker*1.16*  docker*1.15*  docker*1.14*
```

Additionally I would like to install `yum-cron` to perform automatic updates without kernel updates. The documentation tells me that I can do this by adding

`exclude= kernel*` to `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf`

The documentation also says that `# This section overrides yum.conf`

Which leads me to belive that when yum-cron runs it will download and patch all the packages that were excluded in `/etc/yum.conf` since it overwrote the `exclude` directive with the value `kernel*`

Is there a way to merge these to lists for `yum-cron` to honor the exclusions defined in `/etc/yum.conf` and additionally not update the kernel?